# How to get javascript in main page to append to elements in ajax loaded div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, getscript

I'm using the jquery load function to switch out a div. Whenever I load a certain element via ajax that needs javascript to run -it won't work in the div. I know that this is because the element didn't exist in the dom on the initial page load.

I've googled for days and haven't found an answer that can give me an easy to understand explanation. Essentiallly, I'm told to just use `.on` or `$getScript`.

However, this doesn't seem to be the appropriate answer. 
Since, each element loaded in the div has similar properties -I simply want to load the jquery library, and the same two external scripts in my index page's head section -and then make sure that those scripts stay "live" or append to the simple html content that is being externally loaded in the div via ajax.

So, for example, if `page 1` has a div named bouncingcats, and `page 2` has a div named bouncingdogs -that both require an external javascript named 'bounce' -I want to load the javascript file 'bounce' ONE TIME in the head section of my index page -and then dynamically swap out the div named bouncinganimals on my index page with either cats or dogs.

So far, it seems as if the only advice I'm getting is to just put the jquery library AND the *`bounce.js`* file at the end of `page 1` and at the end of `page 2`. This, of course works -but it seems too redundant and of course slows down the ajax load.

Do you know of a way in which I could just load the jquery library and the external javascript page in my index page head once, and have them run when I load content via ajax into my div?

An issue that I have is that I didn't write the script `bounce.js` myself -and it is already minimized -so changing the script could prove to be extremely difficult. Is there something I can just wrap around the external javascript links themselves?

Comment: You don't have to worry about loading scripts twice, usually.  The browser will cache the .js file after the first load (assuming your server settings are correct).

Comment: Does this mean bounce.js doesn't have any methods(w/config) you call to make it work... it does all its stuff only on page load?  Wondering if you can just call them again after new content is loaded.